# BeagleBone Black does not detect USB

Tags: linux, usb, hardware, beagleboneblack, usb-drive

Having trouble accessing the filesystem of a BBB through the USB port.  On connecting the USB, the power turns on, but dmesg doesn't show any new messages.  I can ssh through wlan only.  Tried accessing it through Ubuntu and OSX with no luck.  Other BBB's work fine with my laptop.

Thoughts?

uname -a:

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 01:36:09 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
g_multi                47670  2 
libcomposite           14299  1 g_multi
mt7601Usta            601404  0
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:39:72:14:ec:76  
          inet addr:10.1.10.208  Bcast:10.1.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d239:72ff:fe14:ec76/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:9:4500:3500:d239:72ff:fe14:ec76/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:103712 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7777187 (7.4 MiB)  TX bytes:20177281 (19.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:40 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:9c:ba:f4:23:8a  
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: What usb device do you connect? Have yue tested it on ubuntu/debian? Have you tested it with this bb os in qemu or something?

Comment: I connected the BBB through the client port to my computer and others, tested in Ubuntu, OSX, and Windows with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your usb device is not supported (driver) or it needs to much power. try it with a powered usb hub.

Comment: The BBB is powered off of the DC jack so power shouldn't be an issue.  Connecting to a Linux machine doesn't require a separate driver I think.

Comment: Driver may depend on the device you connect & i don't know bbb tecnical specs but for embedded boards it is quite normal. 3rd possibility might be a short on a usb jack

Comment: it looks like bb has its own os so you may need more drivers then on a ubuntu for example (kernel modules)

Comment: I've tested it with a different wire (one we know to work) and our computers are able to interface with other BBB's with the same uname output so I think there's something wrong with the BBB specifically.

Comment: Reinstall software. Use other sd card. Send it to repair. If it is a defect board how could someone here help you?

Comment: Try different power source for the board, could also be the broken part

Comment: Power source is fine, we use the same one for the other (working) BBB.  Not using an SD card.  Tempted to reinstall the software but I'm afraid that it'll remove our wlan settings and lock us out permanently, is there a way to interface with it directly by some other means?

Comment: Ssh & serial connection. Dhcp working on LAN port. Maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while connecting BeagleBone-Black in Ubuntu using USB Device. Just connect through USB and wait for 2-3 minutes, OS will take some time to recognize it as a USB Device.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent beaglebone (I tested it on blue, but probably it's the same for black, etc):

1. make sure you connect *micro-USB*, as the standard one can only power it
2. add the udev rules, as they say in [getting-started troubleshooting](https://beagleboard.org/getting-started#troubleshooting):

   their script just puts a new rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/73-beaglebone.rules` and reloads udev rules `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`
3. ~10 seconds after power on, it should show up in `lsusb` on your desktop linux as

   ```
   Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1d6b:0104 Linux Foundation Multifunction Composite Gadget
   ```

   plus the log in `journalctl -f` (a long log of configuring it), and a couple new net interfaces in `ip addr`, like

   ```
   enxf45eab539a85: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
     ...
     inet 192.168.6.1/30
   enxf45eab539a82: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
     ...
     inet 192.168.7.1/30
   ```

At that point you should get

- the web page on http://192.168.7.2
- `ssh debian@192.168.7.2` must work
- and it should serve Cloud9 at http://beaglebone.local:3000/